# Python: Emptying temporary list used in a loop without losing referenced information

Tags: python, list

I have following kind of data, which I want to collect to one big list so that each row in the big list has one of these below (c-d and e-f correspond to second and third of these). What I mean is that lista_results[0] includes the first of these and lista_results[1] the second etc.

```
(Name)      (Amount-of-points)
Some name   12
Other name  19
...         ...
```

I have a loop that takes information from other lists and then adds it to result list. The code is along the following lines:

```
lista_results = []
lista_temp = []
for y in range(0,10):
    for x in range(0,10):
        lista_temp.append(name_list[y][x], point_list[y][x])
    lista_results.append(lista_temp)
    #lista_temp[:] = []
```

Without the emptying, all are appended to same list every time x loop finishes. Basically what I get is:

```
[0]["Some name",12]
[0]["Other name",19]
[1]["Some name",12]
[1]["Other name",19]
[1][c,1c]
[1][d,2d]
[2]["Some name",12]
[2]["Other name",19]
[2][c,1c]
[2][d,2d]
[2][e,1e]
[2][f,2f]
...
```

But what I want is:

```
[0]["Some name",12]
[0]["Other name",19]
[1][c,1c]
[1][d,2d]
[2][e,1e]
[2][f,2f]
...
```

Which would mean that I would have to somehow empty the lista_temp after appending it to the lista_results. But when I do empty it (using #lista_temp[:] = []), it seems that also the parts that were appended to lista_results are emptied, or at least I get "IndexError" when trying to print out even lista_results[0][0][0]. I assume that bot reference to same list and emptying either empties also the other.

I also tried lista_newtemp=lista_temp and even then I got an IndexError after emptying lista_temp.

What would be a way to empty lista_temp after append without losing previous information already appended?

(Also, my first question here, I hope I did it well. I hope the problem explanation was clear. Feedback appreciated!)

Comment: where that _a,b,c_.. came from? You have to be more specific

Comment: I agree with @qqvc - although you've got a couple of answers - I'm struggling to understand what the desired output is...

Comment: I tried to make it little bit less confusing to read, I'm not sure if I managed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really hard to tell from your output samples what data you're working on, but it sounds to me like you don't want to empty the list but create a new list for the next iteration. Something like:

```
lista_results = []
for y in range(0,10):
    lista_temp = []     # we have a new lista_temp for every y
    for x in range(0,10):
        lista_temp.append(something_here)
    lista_results.append(lista_temp)
```

The behaviour you see is because Python does not generally make implicit copies. Every lista_temp you appended into lista_results is the same object, which in turn kept changing.

Comment: This was exactly what I was trying to do. Thanks! I actually also managed to solve the problem with using copy.deepcopy, but I think your solution is the one I'll go forward with.

Answer (score 1):

It would be more Pythonic to use [list comprehesions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

The inner list, `lista_temp`, can be created like this:

```
lista_temp = [something_here for x in range(0, 10)]
```

The outer list, `lista_results`, can be created like this:

```
lista_results = [make_lista_temp(y)
                 for y in range(0, 10)]
```

You can combine them, and lose the temporary variable lista_temp:

```
lista_results = [[something_here for x in range(0, 10)]
                 for y in range(0, 10)]
```

**edit:**

Your main problem was that you weren't copying `lista_temp`, so every element of `lista_results` points to the same instance that `lista_temp` points to. You could have copied it like this:

```
lista_results.append(list(lista_temp))
```

However, as above, there are better ways.

Comment: Thanks for introducing the list comprehensions, I will definitely look into those!